# In python, how can I print an imput X times in different lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print an input in a variable and then print that variable several times, but here's the thing, I want it in different lines. Is it possible? Thanks!

```
song = input('song ')   

favorite = song 
print(favorite * 3)

song lala land
lala landlala landlala land
```

Comment: @khelwood yeah I saw that too, but It's not what I ask. I didn't find anything like my question before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list and use `'\n'.join` on it:

```
song = input('song ')

favorite = song

print('\n'.join([favorite] * 3))
```

Or you can make use of the `sep` parameter of the `print` function:

```
print(*([favorite] * 3), sep = '\n')
```